# Is there an isosceles triangle with integers sides?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there an isosceles triangle with integers sides?

I saw this question in a section of integers as sum of squares, on a number theory book. Could someone help me?

Comment: What about an equilateral triangle of sides 1,1,1? Or one with sides 2,2,1?

Comment: In general, if the sidelengths satisfy the triangle inequality then a triangle exists with those sidelengths.  What remains to see is what the angles used are, but if two of the side lengths are equal then two of the angles are equal as well.

Comment: One can split an isoceles triangle into two right angled triangles and there are right angled triangles whose sides are integral (e.g. 3, 4, 5). Not only the sides are integers, the coordinates of its vertices are integers.

Comment: Perhaps you wanted some other condition on the triangle as well, like that the area is also an integer? As it stands, the problem is a trivial one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider any integral-sided equilateral triangle.

Equilateral $\implies$ Isosceles.

Answer (score 2):

An isosceles triangle with sides $a,a,b$ ($>0$) exists if and only if $2a>b$ (i.e. satisfies [Triangle Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality)). If it exists, by the [Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) the angle between the equal sides is equal to $\arccos\left(1-\frac{b^2}{2a^2}\right)$.

So yes, an isosceles triangle with positive integer sides exists. If positive integers $m,n$ satisfy $2m>n$, then an isosceles triangle with sides $m,m,n$ exists.